# How to improve the constrastness of unclear image by opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-enhancement

I am working on a OCR project, but some images are obscure to recognize. I have tried some image enhancement solution but do not find a good one. Is there any suggestion to enhance the following image? thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which implementation (Python, C++, Java, other) of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried Gamma correction, Histgram normalization and CLAHE. I work with Python.